# Source for activity selection, without STL and with Priority Queue and Red&Black

Tags: c++, priority-queue, greedy, red-black-tree

Where i can found something like pseudocode or code, an example to implement this problem
I have founded only something with STL

Comment: I guess activity selection problem just require one sort on finish time of jobs which can be done without using stl.

Comment: If you're talking about the [Activity selection problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem), there's pseudocode on the Wikipedia page.